# How do I install libraries if I don't have the config file

Tags: linux, tar, make, libraries, cmake

How do I install the libraries if I don't have the config file, and in addition to not having the configure file, they come with an extension. I have followed the instructions, I have placed the folder in lib, I have created local in etc, I have used make, cmake, and it does not work. I think I should create the local folder manually in etc and try it. I have looked for how to install them with the extensions, if I should change them, but I can't find a way, I have also looked for a way to install from the files themselves, and since I am not an expert, I can't find a way, if you asked me for guidance, I would be pleased. The library is makeisofs-1.13 downloaded in .tar.gz format

Comment: Being a beginner I suspect you're actually down the wrong path entirely. Tell which OS you're using and what you are trying to achieve.